# Space of complex poynomials

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials

Let $\mathbb{C}_n[z]$ be the space of polynomials (of degree $\le n$) with complex coefficients, let the inner product be $(p,q):=\int_{-1}^1p(t)\overline{q(t)}dt$.

There is one and only one $K_{w} \in \mathbb{C}_n[z]$ such that $p(w)= \int_{-1}^1p(x)\overline{K_{w}(x)}dx, p \in \mathbb{C}_n[z]$.

$p(w) = \sum_{i=0}^n(p,p_i)p_i(w) = \sum_{i=0}^n(p,\overline{p_i(w)}p_i) = (p,\sum_{i=0}^n\overline{p_i(w)}p_i) \iff  K_{w} = \sum_{i=0}^n\overline{p_i(w)}p_i$

How do I extend this to the $l$th derivative $p^{(l)}$ such that $p^{(l)}(w) = (p,K_{w;l})$ and $p^{(l)}(w)= \int_{-1}^1p(x)\overline{K_{w;l}(x)}dx$?

$p^{(l)}(w) = (p^{(l)},\sum_{i=0}^n\overline{p_i(w)}p_i)$, of course, is trivial. How do I move the $l$th derivative from the left-hand side to the right-hand side of the inner product?

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate both sides of 
$$p(w) = \left(p,\sum_{i=0}^n\overline{p_i(w)}p_i\right) $$
with respect to $w$, $l$ times.
$$p^{(l)}(w) = \left(p,\sum_{i=0}^n\overline{p_i^{(l)}(w)}p_i\right) $$
Hence, $$K_{w,l} = \sum_{i=0}^n\overline{p_i^{(l)}(w)}p_i = \frac{d^l}{dw^l}K_w$$

(You did not say this, but I understand $\{p_i\}$ is an orthonormal basis of the space.)

Comment: Thank you so much. You were right, $\{p_i\}$ is an orthonormal basis.